# TFS/Visual Studio 2012: Can't see workflow tab when trying to edit workflow item

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, tfs-workitem

I am trying to add two options to work item states in TFS through Visual Studio 2012. I came accross [this](http://tedgustaf.com/blog/2011/1/how-to-customize-tfs-2010-work-items-and-workflows/) article, but when opening the work item at hand (printscreen 3 in the article), I'm not forwarded to the Workflow tab, but I get some high level XML instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><workItemType dslVersion="3.0.0.0" Name="Bug"
source="http://bla.bla.local:8080/tfs/bla/bla/Bug"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dsltools/WITDesigner" />
```

How do I access the Workflow tab so I can add states to my work item?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the TFS Power Tools to get the graphical editor.  Alternatively you can just edit the XML directly (it's fairly self-explanatory) and use the witadmin.exe command-line tool to import it once you're done editing.

Comment: Hm. I actually installed Power Tools already, and see it's installed in the Extensions and Updates forms as well. Amny thoughts, @Dylan?